# Complex integral over line, similarity with conservative field

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Have $\int_C(4z^2-2iz)dz$ integral.

Does it depend on choice of path?

Tried to express $f(z)=(4z^2-2iz)$, then $f(x+yi)=(4x^2-4y^2+2y)+i(8xy-2x)$

Then $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y}=-8y+2$
And $\frac{\delta Q}{\delta x}=8y-2$

so $\frac{\delta P}{\delta y}=-\frac{\delta Q}{\delta x}$

Does this mean, that integral doesnt depenend on curve choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No!  It would be if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$, not "-".

You could also check that directly.  For example, if you go from z= 0 to z= 1+ i ((0, 0) to (1, 1)) along the straight line y= x, the integral is $\int_0^1 (4x^2- 4x^2+ 2x)dx+ (8x^2- 2x)dx= \int_0^1 8x^2dx= \frac{8}{3}$.

But if you integrate along the line from z= 0 to z= 1, then from z= 1 to z= 1+ i ((0, 0) to (1, 0) then from (1, 0) to (1, 1)) you have $\int_0^1 4x^2 dx+ \int_0^1 8y- 2 dy= \frac{4}{3}+ 4- 2= \frac{10}{3}$.